# What category of categories have faithful functors into Markov categories?

Tags: ct.category-theory

We know that various [Markov categories have deterministic morphisms](https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=ofP7CgYAAAAJ&alert_preview_top_rm=2&citation_for_view=ofP7CgYAAAAJ:W7OEmFMy1HYC).  This suggests that they support faithful functors into them from categories of categories.  One interesting Markov category is the Kleisli Category of the [Distribution Monad](http://nlab-pages.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/nlab/show/distribution+monad), KlDM.  I need to know if KlDM supports a faithful functor into it from one or both of the following categories:

1. The category of small categories
2. The category of finitely presented categories
3. The category of concrete categories

Comment: What is the distribution monad?

Comment: @TimCampion I edited a link into the question. (But the edit needs to be approved.) It's a monad whose underlying functor sends a set to the set of finitely-supported probability distributions over that set. Here's the link: http://nlab-pages.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/nlab/show/distribution+monad

Comment: To the OP, the deterministic subcategory of KlDM is Set, so the question basically boils down to whether you can construct a faithful functor from Cat to Set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following N. Virgo's point (but even more simply), any concrete category $\mathcal C$ admits (by definition) a faithful functor $F: \mathcal C \to Set$. The free functor $G$ from $Set$ to the Kleisli category of the distribution monad is faithful as well. So $GF: \mathcal C \to Kl(Dist)$ is a faithful functor. Conversely, if a category $\mathcal C$ admits a faithful functor $H: \mathcal C \to Kl(Dist)$, then since the forgetful functor $U: Kl(Dist) \to Set$ is also faithful, it follows that $UH$ is faithful, i.e. $\mathcal C$ is concrete. That is, $\mathcal C$ admits a faithful functor to $Kl(Dist)$ iff $\mathcal C$ is concrete.

For example, the category of small categories is concrete (the functor $Mor : Cat \to Set$ which carries a category to its set of morphisms is faithful). Likewise, so is the category of small finitely-presented categories. So these categories are concrete / admit faithful functors to $Kl(Dist)$.

The category of concrete categories is not locally small for any reasonable notion of morphism I can think of, so it is not concrete / it does not admit a faithful functor to $Kl(Dist)$.